# Erlang: rpc:call to remote node crashes with function_clause

Tags: erlang, call, rpc

So I searched around a bit and found that I could use rpc:call/5 to ask a remote node if it got a process registered under a certain name and timeout if the node couldn't be reached, however whenever I try to call rpc:call/5 with the following params:

```
Pid = rpc:call(Node, erlang, whereis, [Name], 3000)
```

It just crashes and I can't figure out which of the param(s) are causing it. The following crash had the params: 'Node=name@0.0.0.0' and 'Name=server'

```
** Reason for termination ==
** "{{function_clause,[{gen,call,[{rex,\"name@0.0.0.0\"},'$gen_call',
{call,erlang,whereis,[\"server\"],<0.24.0>},3000],
[{file,\"gen.erl\"},{line,149}]},{gen_server,call,3,[{file,\"gen_server.erl\"},{line,186}]},
{rpc,'-do_call/3-fun-0-',4,[{file,\"rpc.erl\"},{line,344}]}]},
{gen_server,call,[{rex,\"name@0.0.0.0\"},
{call,erlang,whereis,[\"server\"],<0.24.0>},3000]}}"
12> ** exception error: "{{function_clause,[{gen,call,\n
[{rex,\"name@0.0.0.0\"},'$gen_call',{call,erlang,whereis,[\"server\"],<0.24.0>},3000],
[{file,\"gen.erl\"},{line,149}]},
{gen_server,call,3,[{file,\"gen_server.erl\"},{line,186}]},
{rpc,'-do_call/3-fun-0-',4,[{file,\"rpc.erl\"},{line,344}]}]},\n {gen_server,call,
[{rex,\"name@0.0.0.0\"},{call,erlang,whereis,[\"server\"],<0.24.0>},3000]}}"
```

The node 'name@0.0.0.0' doesn't exist but if that was the problem shouldn't it return with a timeout after 3 seconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're passing the node name as a string, but `rpc:call` expects an atom.  (And likewise for the argument to `whereis`, by the way.)

Try this:

```
Pid = rpc:call(list_to_atom(Node), erlang, whereis, [list_to_atom(Name)], 3000)
```

Or alternatively, pass the arguments as atoms to begin with.  `server` can be passed as is, but `name@0.0.0.0` needs to be quoted, since it contains periods.  Atoms are quoted with single quotes:

```
Node = 'name@0.0.0.0'
```

Comment: Oh, that's why. I don't have much control over how the inparam of Node looks more than it's a name followed by @ and an IP. But list_to_atom did it, thanks a lot!

Comment: A follow up question, if you don't mind: How would I fetch my own name@ip ?

Comment: You can get that by calling `node()`.